# ASP.net:ext.net gridpanel filter change event is not working. How do I implement a column filter event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I implemented listeners to trigger the filterchange of a column filter. But it is not working.

Please find the below code details

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="grvpnlTest" AutoHeight="true" AutoWidth="true" runat="server" StoreID="clstrBilling" StripeRows="true"
    Title="Test Summary">
    <ColumnModel ID="clcmTest" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <ext:NumberColumn Header="ID" DataIndex="ID" Sortable="true" Hidden="true" Width="150" />
            <ext:Column Header="CompanyName" ColumnID="CompanyName" DataIndex="CompanyName" Sortable="true" Width="200" />
            <ext:Column Header="MyID" DataIndex="MyID" Sortable="true">
                <Renderer Fn="Edit" />
            </ext:Column>
            <ext:Column Header="Buy Amount" DataIndex="SellAmount" Sortable="true" Align="Right" />
            <ext:DateColumn Header="Requested Value Date" Format="MMM dd, Y" DataIndex="ReqValueDate" Sortable="true">
            </ext:DateColumn>
        </Columns>
</ColumnModel>
<SelectionModel>
    <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel ID="CheckboxSelectionModel1" runat="server">

        <Listeners>
            <RowSelect Handler="if (!this.lockSelect) {SelectData(record.data.SellAmount); }"></RowSelect>
            <RowDeselect Handler="if (!this.lockSelect) { DeSelectData(record.data.SellAmount);}" />
            <AfterCheckAllClick Handler="afterCheckAllClickHandler(this,checked);" />
            <BeforeCheckAllClick Handler="beforeCheckAllClickHandler(this,checked);" />
        </Listeners>
    </ext:CheckboxSelectionModel>
</SelectionModel>
<Plugins>
    <ext:GridFilters ID="clgfTesting" runat="server">
        <Filters>
            <ext:NumericFilter DataIndex="MyID" />
            <ext:StringFilter DataIndex="SellAmount" />
        </Filters>
        <Listeners>
            <FilterChange Handler="onFilterChange" />
        </Listeners>
    </ext:GridFilters>

 function onFilterChange(grid, filters)
```

{         console.log('Filter change event:', filters);     }